# Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle index.android.bundle is packaged

Tags: react-native

So this has been asked before but I'm asking it again because nothing has worked, I've read through all of the similar posts I could find and all but one has semi fixed the problem.

https://medium.com/@adityasingh_32512/solved-unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-bdc5e3a3d5ff

This medium article is the only solution that i can find that will get debug builds running again but that is only because it is pre packaging the javascript bundle and not really fixing the problem of the app not connecting to the metro server, once the debug build is running via this method I'm unable to shake the device and get the debug menu to show up.

I've been developing this app for probably 10 months, live for 3-4 months, and can usually trudge through these errors that pop up but this one is tricky.

I've been using `cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"`, tried implementing a custom network security config `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"`, tried a different physical device, cleared the metro cache, deleted .gradle/ build folders, cleaned, rebuilt.. All with the same end result of the app crashing on boot and the same error in logcat `Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.`

Release builds work but that's because its not trying to connect to the metro server, pretty stumped on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this for others that might find it useful. Still not sure what I did wrong but in the process of setting up a CI/CD pipeline for the app I re cloned the project and magically android debug builds started working again. No changes to the code, the android project must have gotten corrupted somehow so recloning allowed android studio to start from square one. Weird one.